# Format a markdown string into the output same as like in Github README.md file in the react js or core Html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, markdown, readme

Tech Stack: React(Javascript) / Core html, CSS, Javascript

I have a markdown string output that I need to proper formatting same as Readme file of github with code blocks, string, headings, tables etc all formats.

Example markdown string:

## Heading1

#### Heading 3

```
axios.post('http://example.com/upload', form, {
  headers: form.getHeaders()
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Expected Output:

[image: Markdown output with a code block]

Other markdown formatting string outputs:

[image: Other markdown formatting string outputs]

I have tried with many npm libraries for formatting markdown but I am not able to do it.

I need to format a markdown string into the proper formatting - same as a Github README with a syntax highlighting code block - and copy button with it in react or core HTML, JavaScript.